# Use C++, How to change the above multiple \n into only one \n?

Tags: c++, mfc

```
CString str = _T("111\n\n\n222");
```

How to change the above multiple \n into only one \n?
Cannot use Replace directly, because the number of \n is not fixed

Comment: Just delete the extra `\n`s? Is there a reason you can't just do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (str.Replace("\n\n", "\n") > 0)
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CString::GetBuffer` to obtain a buffer that you can modify.  The corresponding `CString::ReleaseBuffer` allows you to specify a new length for the string.

If you want to remove consecutive characters, you can do this easily by simply walking through the string and rewriting its characters.  Any time you see a character that you wish to remove, simply don't write it and don't update the end-position of the string.

Here's a general-purpose function to remove some number of consecutive characters from a `CString`:

```
void LimitConsecutiveCharacters(CString& str, TCHAR ch, int maxConsecutive = 1)
{
    LPTSTR *begin = str.GetBuffer(0);
    LPTSTR *end = begin;
    int consecutive = 0;
    for (LPTSTR *pos = begin; *pos != _T('\0'); ++pos)
    {
        if (*pos == ch)
        {
            if (consecutive >= maxConsecutive)
                continue;
            ++consecutive;
        }
        else
        {
            consecutive = 0;
        }
        *end++ = *pos;
    }
    int newLength = end - begin;
    str.ReleaseBuffer(newLength);
}
```

As you can see above, it keeps a count of how many consecutive values it has seen for the target character.  If the maximum number of consecutive characters is reached, then it simply moves to the next loop iteration.  Any time it sees some other character, the "consecutive" count resets.

The `end` tracks the position that is being written to, which might even be the same position you're reading from, if you've not removed any characters.  At the end, some simple pointer arithmetic calculates the new string length and calls `CString::ReleaseBuffer`.

An example invocation would be:

```
CString str = _T("111\n\n\n222");
LimitConsecutiveCharacters(str, _T('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `CString` into a `std::wstring`, use `regex_replace` and then convert back to `CString`.

The patterns for the regular expression would be something like:

- find what: `L"\n+"`
- replace by: `L"\n"`